# Background orange text removal from button in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Need to change orange color behind button to white. Dont
know where it comes from the code. Brown text is fine but behind orange one needs it to be removed. Maybe some container is taking a style. Tried removing elevated
button.style from shadow color but still not going. Please help with this. Thanks.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:matab/services/authentication_service.dart';
import 'package:matab/ui/general_widgets/generate_error_snackbar.dart';
import 'package:matab/ui/pages/onBoarding/login_page.dart';
import 'package:simple_gradient_text/simple_gradient_text.dart';

import '../styles.dart';

class SignupTextFields extends StatefulWidget {
  const SignupTextFields({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SignupTextFields> createState() => _SignupTextFieldsState();
}

class _SignupTextFieldsState extends State<SignupTextFields> {
  TextEditingController nameController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController phoneController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController userCnicController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController confirmPasswordController = TextEditingController();

  bool _passwordVisible = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Authentication authentication = Authentication();
    return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                child: Text(
                  'SignUP'.tr,
                  style: const TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 30),
                )),
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: TextField(
                controller: nameController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
                  labelText: 'Name'.tr,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: TextField(
                controller: phoneController,
                inputFormatters: [
                  FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                    RegExp('[0-9]'),
                  ),
                ],
                maxLength: 11,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
                  labelText: 'Phone'.tr,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: TextField(
                controller: emailController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
                  labelText: 'Email'.tr,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: TextField(
                controller: userCnicController,
                inputFormatters: [
                  FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                    RegExp('[0-9]'),
                  ),
                ],
                maxLength: 13,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
                  labelText: 'UserCNIC'.tr,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 0),
              child: TextFormField(
                keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                controller: passwordController,
                obscureText:
                    !_passwordVisible, //This will obscure text dynamically
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
                  labelText: 'Password'.tr,
                  suffixIcon: IconButton(
                    icon: ImageIcon(
                      const AssetImage("assets/visibilty.png"),
                      color: greyColor,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      // Update the state i.e. toogle the state of passwordVisible variable
                      setState(() {
                        _passwordVisible = !_passwordVisible;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 0),
              child: TextFormField(
                keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                controller: confirmPasswordController,
                obscureText:
                    !_passwordVisible, //This will obscure text dynamically
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
                  labelText: 'Confirm Password'.tr,
                  suffixIcon: IconButton(
                    icon: ImageIcon(
                      const AssetImage("assets/visibilty.png"),
                      color: greyColor,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      // Update the state i.e. toogle the state of passwordVisible variable
                      setState(() {
                        _passwordVisible = !_passwordVisible;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 10, 20, 0),
              child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      gradient: LinearGradient(colors: gradientColors),
                      borderRadius:
                          const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(7.0))),
                  height: 50,
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      primary: Colors.transparent,
                      shadowColor: Colors.transparent,
                      shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(82.0)),
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: Text('Register'.tr),
                    onPressed: () {
                      if (nameController.text.isNotEmpty) {
                        if (phoneController.text.isNotEmpty) {
                          if (userCnicController.text.trim().length != 13) {
                            generateError(
                                "Error".tr, "CNICMustBe13DigitsLong".tr);
                          } else {
                            if (emailController.text.isNotEmpty) {
                              authentication.signUp(
                                  nameController.text,
                                  phoneController.text,
                                  int.tryParse(
                                          userCnicController.text.trim()) ??
                                      0, //cnic never replaced with 0 we have already checked for null
                                  emailController.text,
                                  passwordController.text,
                                  confirmPasswordController.text);
                            } else {
                              generateError(
                                  "EmailEmpty".tr, "YouMustProvideEmail".tr);
                            }
                          }
                        } else {
                          generateError(
                              "PhoneCannotEmpty".tr, "EnterPhoneTryAgain".tr);
                        }
                      } else {
                        generateError(
                            "NameCannotBeEmpty".tr, "EnterNameAndTryAgain".tr);
                      }
                    },
                  )),
            ),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  'Already have an Account?'.tr,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: greyColor),
                ),
                TextButton(
                  child: GradientText(
                    'Login'.tr,
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20.0,
                    ),
                    gradientType: GradientType.radial,
                    radius: 2.5,
                    colors: gradientColors,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Get.off(const LoginPage());
                  },
                ),
              ],
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

[image: Button button background]

Comment: Can you include just this single button widget that will produce the issue

Answer (score 2):

For the top container, it is having `Radius.circular(7.0)`  But for Elevated button it is `Radius.circular(82.0)`.

You need to provide same radius on both.

```dart
Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 10, 20, 0),
  child: Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient:
            LinearGradient(colors: [Colors.red, Colors.black54]),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(82.0)),
      ),
      height: 50,
      child: ElevatedButton(
        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
          primary: Colors.transparent,
          shadowColor: Colors.transparent,
          shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(82.0)),
          ),
        ),
        child: Text('Register'),
        onPressed: () {},
      )),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

don't use shadowColor: Colors.transparent, instead use

```
shadowColor: Colors.white,
```

because the default color of your app is orange so if you do Colors.transparent it'll call default color in some cases. Also you have to remove the parent Contanier from the ElevatedButton because it is taking the background surface and changing it to orange color